# Angular2: how to use router-deprecated with ngModule

Tags: angular, module, router

I switched from rc4 to rc5 and bootstrap to a module, main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { PortmanModule } from './portman.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(PortmanModule);
```

portman.module:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {RootComponent} from "./root.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [RootComponent],
    bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class PortmanModule {
}
```

Now when I load my app it yields an error:

**ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!**

main.ts without ngModule, old rc4 syntax works:

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import {RootComponent} from './root.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/router-deprecated";

bootstrap (RootComponent,[
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
]).catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

How do I provide the Router?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to use Router-deprecated with NgModule, but in any case you need to import the reference of the router in your @NgModule imports like this :

**app.modules.ts**

```
...
import { appRouting } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        appRouting, // Routing logic
        LoginModule // Another module
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

**app.routes.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

My best guess would be they also updated router-deprecated to be used with NgModule, but you should check-out the router-deprecated documentation.
Also, my app.routes.ts file is empty because my routing logic is located in the login.routes.ts with the LoginModule, so this is normal.

Comment: Please don't forget to let us know if your problem was solved :)

Comment: I don't know, I switched to the new router

Comment: That would be the best thing to do because things are going to evolve more.